# Can anyone tell me the type of character encoding used within these Strings? [Decompiled]

Tags: java, character-encoding

Currently working on a project for a client that involves re modelling a decompiled and obfuscated set of code from a jar that's rather large.

There's a set of strings that keep popping up to be decoded consistently however the methods to decode said strings have been scrambled to the point of illegibility, from previously asking on here no one has time to be crawling through the method to figure out an alternate solution, so instead figuring out the character encoding is the best way to create a solution for the issue.

*Note that the obfuscator used does not have the ability to encrypt hard coded strings

I've tried varying methods of conversion from different libraries and different character sets however it doesn't seem to be playing ball, I asked a much more complex question here earlier but instead the more effective solution is to begin from knowing how to decode it from the start, below are some examples of the strings.

```
String encodedPriceExample = "\0163J\032'\032J\037\"m\007:P$\031";    
//from interpretation shows a price of a transaction

String encodedErrorMessageExample ="V5T\016\005\"J:\037$\036w\0062\013!\017w\0238\037%J4\037%\0302\004#J1\0134\036>\0059J5\0171\005%\017w\0238\037wO$D"; 
//longer one, should show a no join message of some form.
```

These are only two strings, however all of them look similar and are decrypted via a scrambled static method as previously said.

Does this character encoding look like any character encoding at all? needs to be converted into UTF-8 or Base64.

Due to it going through a decompiler the string itself may just be jumbled and converted into raw unicode of some form, however I've never seen it happen before even with obfuscation, other hard coded strings in the project are fine, just the strings in those static methods.

Any input and / or help would be greatly appreciated in sorting this out! This is more of a check to make sure that my angle for fixing it up is correct.

Thanks guys